# laravel complex text content storage in mysqli databases

Tags: mysqli, laravel-5

there is nothing much about finding out what are the best ways to store complex text content with large number of dynamic headings, subheadings, bullet points and paragraphs in database in laravel 5.2. what are the best and easy ways?.what are the database structures and ways to store multiple headings. saving a post's title and body is something else and is easy. Need help......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `mediumText` or `longText` for your Column....  To begin with; first go to your `Console` and Create a Migration like so:`php artisan make:migration Articles`. Then once the Migration File is created, open it and then add the following lines in the `up()` Method in that file. like this:

```
<?php
    // FILE_NAME: 2016_08_15_163807_Articles.php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

    class Articles extends Migration {

        public function up() {
            // Create table for storing data
            Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('title');
                $table->string('heading')->nullable();
                $table->string('sub_heading')->nullable();
                $table->string('photo')->nullable();
                $table->mediumText('body')->nullable(); //<== ENOUGH FOR COMPLEX TEXT
                //$table->longText('complex_text')->nullable(); //<== MORE THAN ENOUGH FOR COMPLEX TEXT
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Then inside the `app` Directory, create a file called `Article` or you can generate it via Command-Line like so:

```
    php artisan make:model Article
```

To make sure your New Table is created, run:

```
    php artisan migrate
```

Now you have an Article Object which would have properties like `title`, `heading`, `sub_heading`, `photo` and `body`. However it is important to open the `App\Article` class and set one important variable:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Article extends Model {

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'title', 'heading', 'sub-heading', 'photo', 'body'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: will this row add html markup entirely in database? how it works?

Comment: sir thanku so much but i know this stuff. u wrote about migrations and that was use full. i want to know how database should deal with this kind of complex text content

Comment: one confusion is whether to separate the all the headings and subheadings and then save all content to complex_text

Comment: @AhmedKhan   Just think of your Migrations as Table `BluePrints` out of which the real Database Tables will be created.  Once you have a Migration (Blueprint for your Table or DB Table Definition File), the Migration would handle the creation of the Table automatically for you.

Comment: will the table 'complex_text' include all the content including the the html markup?

Comment: @AhmedKhan     Sure... no Problems... That is why it is called a DATABASE Table ;-)

Comment: won't it make database vulnerabel?

Comment: @AhmedKhan       The answer to that question is: ***Where would you otherwise think you could save or store the complex text if not in a Database Table?***  You don't want to go back to Traditional File-Based HTML. Since you are Using Laravel, you have most of the Security issues taken care of. The Rest is up to you as a Developer to implement. Vulnerability issues should be tackled as you go along... but ***keep Primary the focus of "storing your complex text inside of a Database Table..."*** Topmost in your mind....

Comment: thanku so much sir. One last thing. we should extract headings and subheadings and should save them in another column for search purposes right?

Comment: @AhmedKhan     Exactly.... because sometimes, you just want to search the Title and not the content....

Comment: one last thing. and u make a user do this by using a html editor like CKeditor or there are better ways??

Comment: @AhmedKhan      You can use any Editor you like from `tinymce` to `CKeditor` in Laravel. You only have to build those in. May I ask you: What is your main Goal? I mean: What is the nature of the Project you are planning or working on?

Comment: thank u so much sir. my main goal is to take an input from user which consists of a job description. A job description may contains multiple headings, subheadings tables etc. So that is why i was asking

Comment: and also what editor you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: @AhmenKhan     Alright... OK.... It depends on if you want them to be able to submit Rich Text.... But for Job Description(s) etc, Rich Texts are not really necessary so even a normal Textarea would be OK but then, You can also use `tinymce` which is also very easy to integrate.... Since Users would be allowed to add things like Table and other Complex HTML Elements like UL or OL; you may go for `tinymce` or even your favorite `CKeditor`

Comment: ok thanku so much. I also dont like the idea of adding any editor but inside a job description a table and lists are sometimes important thats why i am going for it..

Comment: @AhmedKhan   Where are you from?

Comment: country name Pakistan

Comment: i have sent u an email